# JQuery Sliding Div off of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I am creating a landing page, where what I want to happen, is the page split in half, and either side slide off of the screen, and the main page is left. I almost have it, but what the right side is doing, is whenever the window is at certain sizes, it is going below the left side. I'm not sure quite how to fix this, and everything I try doesn't really work, and there I haven't been able to find any answers online. Thanks for any help

**CODE**

```css
body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#landingDiv {
  min-width: 1100px;
  height: 100vh;
}
#lBanText {
  font-size: 50px;
}
#lBanText p {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.lBan {
  dispay: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  postion: relative;
  float: left;
}
#leftHalf,
#rightHalf {
  min-width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Name of Site
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                
                window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey);
                
                function checkKey(e) {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    //alert(key);
                    if(key === 79) {
                        $("#leftHalf").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
                        $("#rightHalf").hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="landingDiv">
            <div id="leftHalf">
                <div id="lBanText" class="lBan">
                    <p>
                        Title of Website Here
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightHalf">
                <div class="lBan">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the error happening in the snippet you created? I press `o` and am not noticing anything strange.

Comment: change `min-width: 50%` to `width: 50%`

Comment: also... might be wise to maybe do a fiddle. I'm not sure that my solution acutally works for you.

Comment: I'm not getting your error, but it might be fixed by simply setting `#rightHalf` to `float:right;` in your CSS.